# Plugin Install Issue "-1" Appended to end of plugin name

Tags: plugin-development, installation

At some point when zipping `my-plugin.zip` I gave it an incorrect name and installed it, causing my-plugin to fail when opening its admin menus etc.

I then fixed the zip name, and attempted to install `my-plugin.zip`. WordPress says it installed the plugin and I try to activate it, I get the warning

> Warning: require(/var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-1/includes/class-my-plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-1/my-plugin.php on line 1312

It seems to now be looking in `my-plugin-1` instead of `my-plugin` ... I ensured both `my-plugin` and `my-plugin-1` folders do not exist in `wp-content/plugins` before installing the plugin - But the issue persists - Any ideas?

Comment: the folder name of your plugin shouldn't be an issue, you should be able to give it any name and activate it, and it would still work. Are you hardcoding the plugin folder name in your PHP code? Did you delete the previous plugin you uploaded? I notice there is no code to debug in your question

Comment: The plugin folder is not hardcoded at line 1312.
```require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-my-plugin.php';```
Looking at server file system, it is definitely creating the my-plugin-1 folder even despite my-plugin not existing... However the owner of the folder is different to other plugins for some reason...

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you using? And did you delete the plugin before re-uploading it? And have you confirmed that your zip file contains the correct version of the code? Have you considered using FTP to upload it instead?